# Is there any way to calculate mean() of first five columns of Dataframe.groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe that has different length each group.
For example,

```
gid val1 val2
1   3    5
1   11   15
1   12   5
1   18   6
1   8    8
1   18   7
1   18   8
2   29   21
2   27   23
....
```

Then, I want to perform

```
def func(x):
  d = {}
  d['first2'] = x['val1'].first(5).mean()
  return pd.Series(...)
grouped = df.groupby(['gid']).apply(func)
```

that way I can get the mean() of first five columns of x['val1'] which is in the same group.

1. Is there any way to perform above operations?
2. Is there any way to perform above operations but with latter half columns rather than first five columns?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do You want the mean of first 5 columns? It looks like you want the mean of first 5 rows

Comment: `df.groupby('id').cumcount()` will give you the row number within group.

Comment: `.groupby().head(5)` gives you first five rows, while `groupby().tail(5)` gives you the last 5?

Comment: @WJun Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you have sample data sets and expected results, it will be helpful for anyone to answer.

Comment: Sorry. For more details, there are 7 rows that are in Group 1 as presented above. However, instead of getting mean() of each Group, I want to use only the first five rows of group1 to calculate mean of Group1. For example, val1 of Group1 is [3,11,12,18,8,18,18] but the expected result would be mean(3, 11, 12, 18, 8).